# Shape results returned in Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: json, azure, azure-cognitive-search

Up until recently, there was some kind of auto-wrapping of merged content and content in the results returned from Azure Cognitive Search, meaning that results returned fitted inside the window and were reasonably easy to read.

[image: Old style text returned]

It now goes off in one single straight line for the length of the preview and has to be scrolled sideways to see the text.

[image: New style text returned]

Does anyone have any tips for how to encode this wrapping function into the JSON definition for the index?

Answer (score 1):

1. Created azure search index and indexed few documents.
2. I have performed search in azure search explorer and search results are as returned as shown below

**Format of Request URL:**  `https://[service  name].[search.windows.net/indexes](http://search.windows.net/indexes "http://search.windows.net/indexes")/[index name]/docs?[query parameters]`

**Request Type**: `Get`
**Request Headers**:  `Content-Type: application/json`
**Api-key**: `[admin or query key]`

[image]

4. As highlighted in above screenshot, For the document **21583473018.pdf.docx,** content and merged_content are in a single line and need to scrolled to sideways to view all the content.
5. You can use postman to call the search service and the search results are auto-wrapping in Json format.
6. Using postman, I have called the search service Api and getting results as shown below:

[image]

Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents#uri-parameters) to call search service through postman.